# Input mask for partial date without year in vba

Tags: winforms, vba, ms-access-2007

I have the below input mask which take in the date format: 21/10/98

```
00/00/00;0;_
```

But i need to be in the below format : 21/10 
(without year)

This syntax of input mask shown below

```
00/00;0;_
```

is not giving the right answer.

If we right click on the text box of vba form and take the input mask property, there is an option to fill input mask which will mask the input in particular format. If I put the above code `00/00/00;0;_` now it will take `DD/MM/YY` format but I don't want year so I put `00/00;0;_` , but it's still taking year.

Answer (score 0):

the behaviour of this property is dependent on your locale settings defined in "Regional Settings Properties" in your control panel.

you may want to take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa160023(office.10).aspx)

without seeing the code and the output it's difficult to see the problem. could you post some?

regards

Comment: If we right click on the text box of vba form and take the input mask property. there is option to fill input mask which will mask the input in particular format. If i put the above code 00/00/00;0;_ now it will take DD/MM/YY format but i donot want year so i put 00/00;0;_ , but its still taking year.. this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both the mask and the format. Mask should be 00/00 and the format mm/dd.

I'm not sure why you felt the need to post this twice. I already offered comments/answer in this version of the question:

[Input Mask without Year for date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194493/input-mask-without-year-for-date)

Note that I caution there that you might very well consider not using a date field at all, given that you'll have unpredictable years, and will need to ignore the year part, which means you won't get much advantage out of any index on the field.